# Using a string as an index in typescript

Tags: typescript, casting, typescript-generics

I am trying to type the following

```
    interface IStudentType {
      [key: `${Students}`]: IStudent | IStudentMaths| IStudentPhysics
     }
```

The issue I get is **TS1268: An index signature parameter type must be 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or a template literal type.**

Fair enough so I try

```
type StudentCategories = 'Mature' | 'Graduate' | 'Fresher' // these are the keys in the data

interface IStudentType {
  [key: `${StudentCategories}`]: IStudent | IStudentMaths| IStudentPhysics
}

TS1337: An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: it's hard to understand the context here, for what you're trying to accomplish. anyways, you cannot use a runtime value like `${StudentCategories}` in your key index type.

Comment: if you can provide more context for what you're trying to model, with the students information here, surely we can help point towards an elegant solution

Comment: You should use `Record` for this. Example: `type StudentType = Record<StudentCategories, IStudent | IStudentMaths | IStudentPhysics>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a union of keys, you should use [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

```js
type StudentCategories = 'Mature' | 'Graduate' | 'Fresher' // these are the keys in the data

type IStudent = {
    tag: 'IStudent '
}

type IStudentMaths = {
    tag: 'IStudentMaths'
}
type IStudentPhysics = {
    tag: 'IStudentPhysics'
}

type StudentType = Record<StudentCategories, IStudent | IStudentMaths | IStudentPhysics>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wR5jvW)

It is possible to use [Symbol and Template String Pattern Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) and [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512) but then you need to add a prefix:

```js
interface StudentType {
    [prop: `${string}-${StudentCategories}`]: IStudent | IStudentMaths | IStudentPhysics
}
```

Comment: Where do you intend the `[Record][1]` link to go?